# Accessing NSManagedObject Data

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I'm working with Core Data. There are two `ViewController`, in my `SecondViewController` I'm using `fetchData()` method as shown below, to fetch data which I've stored in my `FirstViewController`.

```
 func fetchData() {
            var person = [NSManagedObject]()
            let appDel = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
            let managedContext = appDel.managedObjectContext

            let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "People")

            do{
                let results = try managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)
                person = results as! [NSManagedObject]
            } catch let error as NSError {
                print("Could not fetch data \(error)")
            }

            print(person)
    }
```

By printing `counters` I've verified there are 2 `data: <fault>` which I've learnt that my data is actually there, but its a memory saving technique.

For my Core Data, I have an entity named `People` with attributes `firstName`, `lastName` and `address`.

My question would be how do I work with `NSManagedObject` to extract all my data in `person`? (2 objects with 3 attributes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
      func fetchData() {

           var peoples  = [People]() // Where People = your NSManaged Class
           var fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "People")
           let appDel = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
           let context = appDel.managedObjectContext

           do
           {    
             peoples = try context.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as! [People]
           } 
           catch let error as NSError
           {
             print("Could not fetch data \(error)")
           }
           // Then you can use your propertys.
           for people in peoples {
             print("FirstName: \(people.firstName)  LastName: \(people.lastName)   Address: \(people.address)")   
           }

     }
```

Its better to return Array of objects from fetchData method and use it in `secondViewController`.

Comment: However, in my app, users can access `SecondViewController` directly without going to `FirstViewController` first. Would that work too?

Comment: No, in this case, it will not work, if fetchData is written in firstViewController then user must go though it. If you want to make fetchData independent of FirstViewController then move it to SecondViewController or something centralized like 'AppDelegate'.

Comment: The structure of my app is where `FirstViewController` is meant for storing, while `SecondViewController` is meant for accessing. Users can quit the app, upon launching, they can immediately access `SecondViewController`. From what you are saying, I can place my `fetchData()` in `SecondViewController` with NSManaged class, it should work?

Comment: Yes it will definitely work with you app flow as accessing data has nothing to do with storing mechanism they are independent of each other and It will be a good approach to place fetchData in SecondViewController. please accept the answer if its helpful for you.

Comment: Yes will test it out and accept your answer. However, I need to figure out how to do my NSManaged class first. Sorry I'm new to swift, I've created my NSManaged subclass, however in that subclass, do create `String` properties there?

Comment: generate sub classes with automatic process using Xcode.

Comment: Error running this line. `peoples = try context.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: nil) as [People]`

Comment: Apologies. Noob mistake. However u need to amend your answers a little. Need to remove `error: nil` and there is missing of this line `let context = appDel.managedObjectContext`